# Python: Rotate data from vertical to horizontal in text file

Tags: python-2.7, text, vertical-alignment, horizontalscrollview

Using python how to rotate data in text file from vertical alignment to horizontal alignment.
Example:

```
T
h
i
s

v
e
r
t
i
c
a
l

t
e
x
t
```

And i want it to be like this:

```
This is horizontal text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that every character in your input is separated by a `\n` (Line break) char, all you need to do is replace them with nothing.

If you are reading from a file you will need this code:

```
with open("PATH TO FILE.txt", r) as file:
    input = file.read()
```

To Replace `\n` characters with spaces you will need:

```
input.replace("\n", "")
```

Now just combine the two code snippets

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just literally pivot the text in the text file, you can read it into a dataframe and transpose it using the below.

Once its in a dataframe, you can do anything you want with it. Write it back to a flat file, do calculations and further manipulations, etc.

[image]

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

**Further Reading/ Resources**

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

[How to transpose lines to column for only 7 rows at a time in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725697/how-to-transpose-lines-to-column-for-only-7-rows-at-a-time-in-file)

Comment: @nater303 glad to help buddy