# convert multiple columns vertical text to horizontal

Tags: python, notepad++, text-processing

I tried these, but its only for one column.
using [notepad++](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/11627/how-to-make-the-vertical-text-to-horizontal-text/3) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080587/python-rotate-data-from-vertical-to-horizontal-in-text-file). Any solution that can do for multiple columns of text?

```
# Input:
tim
oso
d n
a d
y a
  y

# Output:
today 
is 
monday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with a loop, something like:

```
s = "tim\noso\nd n\na d\ny a\n  y"
bits = s.split('\n')
lines = ['' for i in range(0, len(bits[0]))]
for bit in bits:
  for i in range(0, len(bit)):
    if bit[i] != ' ':
      lines[i] += bit[i]
'\n'.join(lines)
```